# What exactly does a stored procedure return in ExecuteReader?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

If I have a stored procedure like this:

```
...
set @query = N'select @total = count(*) from (...)';
exec sp_executesql @query @total output;

return
```

Now in C# code I open a ExecuteReader, execute this stored procedure and start reading, what am I actually reading? Is it the result from exec or from return? If it's from the exec, isn't the exec just setting variable total to some value? How come the ExecuteReader in my code still reading rows normally?

I am just so confused about the way ExecuteReader works with stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteReader reads any result sets that your query returns. If your query had three SELECTs in it then ExecuteReader will give you access to all three of those result sets. You would use `reader.NextResult()` to move between sets.

If your query includes a call to EXEC which in turn produces a result set (perhaps the procedure you call with EXEC contains a SELECT) then ExecuteReader will read that result set.

It doesn't hook up to anything apart from the result sets that your query returns.

For further information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So in my code above, if I have another select in from(), although it is just a part of the whole query, but it still generates a result set?

Comment: If you mean something like `SET @query = N'select @total = COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM Foo)'` then no. There would be no result set returned, `@total` would just get set to the count of the `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

Certainly `output` is a keyword that tells the stored procedure what should be the output variable when it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You will read nothing because no result set is being created. You just assign into a variable.

Comment: The first call to `Read` will return false. There's no result set to be read. No rows. It is as if you had executed the string `" "` which also returns nothing (but is a valid batch).

Comment: I mean generally, does it read from exec? Then what does return do?

Comment: Exec has nothing to do with result sets. `SELECT` can generate a result set. It does not return a set to the caller, it directly pipes rows to the client. Procedures do not return result sets, `SELECT` does. it does not matter where the `SELECT` is positioned.

Comment: @Xufeng only top-level `SELECT`'s generate result sets. Nested `SELECT`s are called derived tables. They are not statements and do not exist independently.